# Saving all open files in Photoshop (CS5)

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have learned that Photoshop does not come with a "Save all" command. However, I would like to have such a command.

**What I found on the web:**

I read [here](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080715072819AA1XaOe) that I can record the action of saving a file, and then associate it with a key so that I can trigger that action later using a keystroke. However, wouldn't that be the same as going through my files one by one and then using Ctrl-S to save each individual file? How can I run an action on every open file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do this by first making an action that saves a file with the settings you want.

After you have that action, do the following:

file -> action -> batch -> source(all open files)

select the action that you just made

run the batch script

there, you are done!

edit to include tip:
If you want to bind a key such that hitting it will save all open files, you can do the following:

1) Create another action that runs a batch of the action saving open files

2) bind this action to the key of your choice

3) Hit the chosen key to save all open files
[image: Final Action]

Comment: any way an auto-generated filename could be implemented into this (e.g. date or anything)?

Comment: `File > Scripts > Image Processor`  as mentioned by @user3284178 is a better way to do this.

Answer (score 9):

I'm late to the show, but I thought I'd share what I found for future reference. I'm using Photoshop CC 2016, and had the same problem. My solution was to go to `File > Scripts > Image Processor`, and use the following settings:

1) Check `Use Open Images`.

2) Click `Select Folder`, navigate to the desired target folder. Then mark the radio button next to `Select Folder`.

3) Check `Save as JPEG`. Set Quality to desired value.

4) Uncheck `Run Action` at the bottom. This would be used to apply another correction / effect to all photos before saving, such as a vignette or dropping to grayscale.

5) Click `Run` in the top right.

This makes a folder called "`JPEG`" in the specified target directory, and stores your images inside. Then, simply click `File > Close All` to close all open files at once.

Comment: This is perfect!

Answer (score 2):

You can use an action in a batch command. Look under `File` > `Automate` > `Batch` for the tool. You can apply your action to all open images, or specify a folder of images as your source.

[image: Photoshop CS5 batch tool]

Comment: Thanks @Brian, is there a way of associating the batch with a keystroke?

Comment: @AmV Not exactly directed at me, but yes you can. Save the batch as a action and bind the action to a key

Comment: Thanks @aCuria. If you edit your answer to include this tip, I'll accept it as the final answer!

Comment: @aCuria afaik the action recorder does not watch the batch window.

Comment: I tested it before posting. Using CS5 here, and so is the OP

Comment: In my case, I have to check **Override Action 'Save As' Command**,     otherwise Save As dialog box kept on popping out.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to save a copy really quickly, you can use > Scripts > Image Processor > Use Open Images > Save as PSD.

Comment: The answer was already accepted. Also would this save all the images at once individually?